# Divide an integer by 2 by replacing 9 with 0

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

What are examples of integers that halve their values when all 9's in their decimal representations are replaced with 0's?

Comment: is this in base 10?

Comment: Yes. [Decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal).

Comment: Ah see, when I see decimal I think **'.'** not base 10. It's the programmer in me I think.

Comment: Replace 0->9 or 9->0 ??

Comment: @ABcDexter Replace nines with zeroes. So (e.g.) $2989$ becomes $2080$.

Comment: @DooplissForce please read the question title again.

Comment: @GOTO0 Welcome :) I don't think there is a solution to [this](http://ideone.com/EJCdXy), but again, `lateral-thinking` says it all :)

Comment: I'm not sure [tag:lateral-thinking] is appropriate here.

Comment: Already resolved by ffao and McFry, and to prove there is no other classic solution then 0, it is almost trivial if you reverse the question into: which integers are multiplied by 2 if some of  0's are replaced by 9.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not the usual decimal representation, but...

> $1.9999999....$ is double $1.00000... $

I originally did not point this out as to not complicate the answer, but we can make as many examples as we want:

> Just move the decimal point in the previous answer to the right:
>  $19.999999....$ is double $10.0000... $
>  $199.99999....$ is double $100.000... $
>  and so on.

Comment: This is pretty much what I was going to answer, Playing on the fact that both **integers** and **decimals** are mentioned

Comment: Moving the decimal point around creates other numbers that also satisfy the property.

Comment: Congratulations, every integer has two decimal representations. @McFry I think your comment deserves to become an answer (0, 2, 20, 200 ...and their negatives).

Comment: If we don't use classic/natural representation then almost everything is possible ! for example  $36=18+9+9 $ which is the double of $18+0+0=36/2$

Comment: @Lordofdark But that representation is not a [decimal representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_representation), as the question asks for.

Comment: But the solution here is **not** integer at all... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer

Comment: It is, that number is just more commonly written as 2. I'd rather not explain math in comments of a puzzling site, but see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/is-it-0-999999999-ldots-1-true

Comment: This answer definitely **isn't** using integers, but rather real numbers (in particular, a limit of a rational function).

Comment: @Rhymoid Integers are a subset of real numbers. There is no rule that a limit of whichever real or even complex function or sequence cannot be an integer.

Comment: @z100 I concur that there is a conventional isomorphism between the integers and a subset of the real numbers. I disagree that they contain the same objects. A [good question on this subject](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1055501/44190) can be found on math.SE.

Comment: @Rhymoid Thanks for a link on an interesting discussion. It depends which space those objects are embedded in, mainly depends on operations required or allowed and topology. In this case I think the key word is "decimal representation", which on first sight, leads out from binary, ternary, hexadecimal and so on systems, but "laterral-thinking" points to 2nd option of representing the integer, except 0, which is not interesting.  For topologyst, a coffee cup is the same as compact disc.

Comment: @Rhymoid, no, these ARE integers.  An integer is a number that CAN be written without anything after the decimal point - it's not any particular representation of that number.  It doesn't matter whether you write it as `2` or as `1.99999...` or as `(999 / 37) ^ (1/3) - 1` - it's still the same integer.

Comment: 1.99999999.... is not an integer.

Comment: Yes, it is.  1.999... = 2

Answer (score 32):

This is kinda cheap, but:

> $0$ works, since replacing all of the nines in $0$ (all zero of them) results in $0$, and $\frac{0}{2} = 0$.

Comment: Is this trivial solution the only one that exists?

Comment: Yes. See proof below.

Comment: @A. Mirabeau See my comment under original question.

Answer (score 19):

One solution is:

> **0**... and this is also the **only whole-number solution**!

Explanation:

> * If you take a number containing at least one 9 and subtract the same number with all 9s replaced by 0s, then the difference between them will consist of some sequence of 0s and 9s.
>  * Specifically, the difference contains a 9 in every place value in which a 9 in the minuend (the original number, before the minus sign) is replaced by a 0 in the subtrahend (the replaced number, after the minus sign). All other digits of the difference are 0s.
>  * So the difference has a 9 in each place value where the minuend has a 9 and the subtrahend has a 0, and the difference has 0s in all other place values.
>  * If the substitution process halves the minuend (the original number), then the difference must be equal to the subtrahend (the subtracted and replaced number, after the minus sign).
>  * If the subtrahend and the difference are equal, then all their digits -- in all place values -- must be identical.
>  * But recall that wherever the difference has a 9, the subtrahend has a 0.
>  * So the difference can contain only 9s and 0s, and if the minuend is halved, it can't contain any 9s. Therefore, it must contain only 0s, making it equal to 0.
>  * Therefore, the subtrahend is also 0.
>  * And solving x - 0 = 0 for x, the minuend is also 0.

Comment: +1 - But why would equal numbers necessarily contain identical digits in all places?

Comment: They don't, if you're using the solution that is currently the most upvoted. However, this proof applies to the situation in which one doesn't take this "shortcut".

Comment: ffao's answer includes an infinite set of solutions that are also whole numbers.

Comment: You know what I mean.

Comment: @Paulpro - Except those answers are not *integers*, which is what was being asked for.  By necessity, those 1(9).999... solutions are all decimals.

Comment: @ricdesi Saying that `1.999...` isn't an integer is the same as saying that `2` isn't an integer. They're two representations of the same number. That's similar to saying that `4/2` isn't an integer just because it's represented as a rational number. It's still `2`.

Comment: This is a great explanation and @GOTO0's comment points to the exact assumption that invalidates it, making the .9999 solutions possible.

Comment: @Paulpro I disagree.  `1.999...` is not an integer, it's a simplification of the geometric series `1+Σ[9*.1ⁿ]` whose limit is `2`.

Comment: @Paulpro `4/2` has an exact value which is equivalent to `2`, `1.999...` approaches a *limit* of `2`, which invalidates it as an integer.

Comment: @ricdesi Interesting perspective. I would argue that the presentation doesn't matter, and that no matter if I write `2`, `two`, `the square root of four`, `II`, `10 (base 2)`, `two`, `6*20/60`, `1+Σ[9*.1ⁿ]`, or `1.999...`, those are all just representations of the integer `2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

> 4 + 5 + 9
>  It's not *the* decimal representation, but that could be held against other answers too ...

Comment: But that's not the value, it's the representation and it does specify decimal representation

Comment: @Areeb The substitution applies to the representation while the value halves. However, arguably the phrasing '_the_ decimal representation' in the problem statement might be seen to imply that this kind of solution is not permitted. Otoh ... ;-)

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: it's probably because you said no constraints on the representation while there are in fact constraints. It would've been a good answer if not for that

Comment: @Areeb Good point. I should remove that claim.

Comment: that would be best, and also Welcome to Puzzling!

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this:

> 1.9999999999999999999999 ~ 2

Would become this:

> 1.0000000000000000000000 = 1

Which is half the former value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this(or something similar) has already been said...

Comment: Yeah, I tried to answer before seeing the answers