# An omalonumerophobic's number sequence

Tags: number-sequence, formation-of-numbers

Find all seven terms of the number sequence,

> a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>4</sub>, a<sub>5</sub>, a<sub>6</sub>, a<sub>7</sub>

given that

> - each successive term is exactly twice the value of the previous term
> - no even digits are used in writing the terms

The a<sub>i</sub> are integers written in decimal notation.

Thanks to @GOTO 0 for the [inspiration](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/38494/divide-an-integer-by-2-by-replacing-9-with-0).

Comment: Yes - thanks boboquack - your words are good (and help to rule out more lateral thinking).

Comment: @Tom they're your words :P

Comment: Decimal notation definitely means base 10, correct?

Comment: Yes, base ten decimal representation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The numbers could be

> $5, 9.\bar{9},19.\bar{9},39.\bar{9},79.\bar{9},159.\bar{9},319.\bar{9}$.

It's easy to check that all the conditions are satisfied; however, I don't know if this set is unique.

Answer (score -2):

Well, based on the answer of Ankonganit, perhaps, here is another one:

> .5, 1, 1.9999..., 3.9999..., 7.9999..., 15.9999..., 31.9999...

Comment: .5 is not an integer, as required by the question.